# I cannot get the note timing right - XNA

Tags: xna

In XNA I've created a note sequence, and I'm trying to get the item to be drawn to the screen at a certain time? my check for this is a simple int that gets updated as the gametime does        Convert.ToInt64(time)
is the code for that. However the only problem I got was it seemed that it kept drawing it which made the note lag? Could somebody please help?

Comment: doesn't the update loop give you a `dt`?

Comment: it's the change in time since the last update loop

Comment: I'm not too sure to be honest, I'm new to XNA, so I thought it'd be appropriate to make a string that contains the amount of minutes, seconds and milliseconds. I considered that useful because all the notes in the XML file could simply be added at for e.g 0:40:34

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Create a global variable that check if you draw it or not.
Once you draw it make it true.
In the update, do:
if(!variable&&time>"yourtime")
...